# how to reuse es6 class in vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

How to reuse some existing ES6 classes in Vue Js.

Have a class which has a variable being updated by observable.

```
class A { 
    public a: string;
    someobservable.subscribe((a) =>{
         this.a = a;
    })
}
```

In vue.JS  have created the object of this class.

Sample how property is been used:

```
created: {
    objA = new A();
}
methods: {
    getA() {
        if(this.objA !== undefined){
            return objA.a;
        }
    }
}
```

and in vue template:

```
<div>{{getA()}}</div>
```

**The value in template gets out of sync with value of variable in class.**

Is there any other way to use the property in Vue template that it keeps updating real time.

Comment: Use computed property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work with `getA()` as a computed property rather than a method. Also, you can skip the if statement as no return statement will return `undefined`.

```js
computed: {
  getA() {
    return objA.a;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi using it in computed worked pretty well. Thanks. actually, we use typescript with Vue.extend so that condition was necessary.

Comment: Cheers, glad that works for you. I haven't used Typescript with Vue, but in Angular (for example) can usually type as `any` to circumvent TS-specific error messages. (So maybe `getA(): any {` gets around it).

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the instance in the global scope. You need to instantiate your object in the `data` field for vue to be able to track any changes ..

```
data: {
    objA: new A();
},
```

Then you can either use a method like you did ..

```
methods: {
    getA() {
       return this.objA.a;
    }
},
```

---

```
<div>{{getA()}}</div>
```

Or use a computed property like others have said ..

```
computed: {
    getA() {
       return this.objA.a;
    }
}
```

---

```
<div>{{getA}}</div>
```

Both will have the same effect, but it's better to use a computed property to take advantage of the caching.

Comment: both the solutions are pretty good and working. I couldn't create it in data as object creation depends on something else. Thanks.